# how can I recursively flatten arbitrarily nested vectors and maps in Clojure?

Tags: recursion, clojure, tree, nested, flatten

I am trying to use recursion to walk a tree of arbitrarily nested vectors and maps in Clojure, and return a vector of just the keywords, including the tops.

So the below sample data should return:

`[:top :top :top :top :top :top :top :top :bottom :bottom :bottom :bottom :bottom :bottom :bottom :bottom :bottom :bottom :bottom :bottom]`,

but in no particular order.

Could somebody please help me to do this correctly? Below is what I have so far.

```
(def sample [{:top {:top {:top [:bottom {:top {:top [:bottom :bottom :bottom]}} :bottom :bottom :bottom]}}}, 
                        {:top {:top [:bottom :bottom :bottom]}}, 
                        {:top [:bottom :bottom]}])

(defn make-flat [graph]
  (loop [graph graph]
    (if (every? keyword? graph) graph
      (recur (into graph (flatten (seq (first (filter #(not (keyword? %)) graph)))))))))

(make-flat sample)
```

Comment: Why do you have such an arbitrarily nested sequence to begin with? It's usually possible, and better, to just produce data that's shaped right to begin with, than apply this weird fix to it.

Comment: It's a coding challenge :)

Comment: If it's a coding challenge, and I give you the answer, do I get credit for solving the coding challenge?

Comment: I've actually already solved the challenge, but I'm personally looking for a more general solution to the problem I outlined above. I can give you credit by accepting your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if your data is not nested very deeply (like hundred of levels down), you could simply use the recursion:

```
(defn my-flatten [x]
  (if (coll? x)
    (mapcat my-flatten x)
    [x]))
```

in repl:

```
user> (my-flatten sample)
(:top :top :top :bottom :top :top :bottom :bottom :bottom 
 :bottom :bottom :bottom :top :top :bottom :bottom 
 :bottom :top :bottom :bottom)
```

otherwise i would agree that tree-seq is really nice variant here:

```
user> (filter keyword? (tree-seq coll? seq sample))
(:top :top :top :bottom :top :top :bottom :bottom 
 :bottom :bottom :bottom :bottom :top :top :bottom 
 :bottom :bottom :top :bottom :bottom)
```

Comment: I also like the tre-seq solution a lot and it can handle large, deeply nested inputs, but the recursive solution is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Look at the source of flatten:

```
(defn flatten
  "Takes any nested combination of sequential things (lists, vectors,
  etc.) and returns their contents as a single, flat sequence.
  (flatten nil) returns an empty sequence."
  {:added "1.2"
   :static true}
  [x]
  (filter (complement sequential?)
          (rest (tree-seq sequential? seq x))))
```

You can now just change `sequential?` to `coll?` to include the maps. Further if you want to only get the keywords you can also add `every-pred`:

```
(defn flatten' [x]
  (filter (every-pred (complement coll?) keyword?)
          (rest (tree-seq coll? seq x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspected there is already a function which does this in clojure.clj = the clojure fundamental libraries

Surely enough, there is

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/flatten

However, if you are doing this to learn about how it actually happens, you can look at the source code on github for the function (flatten stuff) where stuff is the stuff you want to flatten.

Notice that for maps you must use a workaround by invoking seq.

```
 (seq the-map-you-wanna-flatten-eventually)
```

user=> (flatten {:name "Hubert" :age 23})
()

```
; Workaround for maps

user=> (flatten (seq {:name "Hubert" :age 23}))
(:name "Hubert" :age 23)
```

Comment: flatten only works on sequences, which maps are not. You can do `(flatten (seq my-map))`, as a workaround, but it does not go more than one level deep...

Comment: @kurofune That's not quite correct; `flatten` works on anything that's [`sequential?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sequential_q), which includes things (like vectors) that might not necessarily be sequences.

Comment: @SamEstep Thanks for the tidbit

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at `postwalk`  here  http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/postwalk

Also see `postwalk-demo`:  http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/postwalk-demo

Here is a working program:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:use tupelo.core)
  (:require [clojure.walk :refer [postwalk]] )
)

(def result (atom []))

(defn go [data]
  (postwalk (fn [it]
              (spyx it)
              (when (keyword? it)
                (swap! result append it))
              it)
            data))

(newline)
(spyx (go {:a 1 :b {:c 3 :d 4}}))
(spyx @result)
```

with result:

```
it => :a
it => 1
it => [:a 1]
it => :b
it => :c
it => 3
it => [:c 3]
it => :d
it => 4
it => [:d 4]
it => {:c 3, :d 4}
it => [:b {:c 3, :d 4}]
it => {:a 1, :b {:c 3, :d 4}}
(go {:a 1, :b {:c 3, :d 4}}) => {:a 1, :b {:c 3, :d 4}}
(clojure.core/deref result) => [:a :b :c :d]
```

Using your data, the final output is:

> (clojure.core/deref result) => [:top :top :top :bottom :top :top
>   :bottom :bottom :bottom :bottom :bottom :bottom :top :top :bottom
>   :bottom :bottom :top :bottom :bottom]

Here is a simple recursive solution:

```
(def mm {:a 1 :b {:c 3 :d 4}})

(defn accum 
  [it]
  (spy :msg "accum" it)
  (when (keyword? it)
    (swap! result append it)))

(defn walk [data]
  (spy :msg "walk" data)
  (cond
    (coll?  data)  (mapv walk data)
    :else          (accum data)))

(newline)
(reset! result [])
(walk mm)
(spyx @result)
```

With output:

```
walk => {:a 1, :b {:c 3, :d 4}}
walk => [:a 1]
walk => :a
accum => :a
walk => 1
accum => 1
walk => [:b {:c 3, :d 4}]
walk => :b
accum => :b
walk => {:c 3, :d 4}
walk => [:c 3]
walk => :c
accum => :c
walk => 3
accum => 3
walk => [:d 4]
walk => :d
accum => :d
walk => 4
accum => 4
(clojure.core/deref result) => [:a :b :c :d]
```

Comment: This is a great working solution, but I am actually trying to solve the problem using recursion. I am sure there is a really simple way to do it.